Computing an integral involving product of Bessel functions
I am trying to evaluate the following definite integral:
$$\int_0^\infty J_\mu(ax^2)J_\nu(bx) dx$$
where:
$J_\mu$ and $J_\nu$ are Bessel functions of the first kind
$a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ are real constants
$\mu, \nu$ are the orders of the respective Bessel functions
Is there a closed form solution for this integral?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

MSE is not a "do my homework/work for me" site. Posts like this (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, & often downvoted & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.

@PrincessEev It is not a homework, i need this integral in my thesis, if you have a refrence that found  general form of this integral please give it to me, because i could not find this integral yet.
